# How to plot Smith chart

Tags: matlab, smith-chart

I need to plot Smith chart, having frequency, VSWR, reflection coefficient and phase. I'm aware there's `smithchart` command in matlab and as an argument I should use reflection coefficient, but my chart looks not as it should (below the chart you can see my rho values):
[image]
As far as I know, as an output I should get something similiar to this:
[image]

So my question is: is there any program that will help me with this task, using values that I mentioned in the first line? So far I've found something called [`Smith`](http://www.fritz.dellsperger.net/smith.html), but it would be rather tiresome to manually add dozens of points. Still, if it's the easiest way to plot Smith chart, I'll go with it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the values you gave for `rho` are all real numbers.

And it looks like Matlab plotted some values along the real axis:

[image]

If you want to get a result like your other example, you should provide complex values of the reflection coefficient, not just the magnitude or real part.

If you were simulating the reflection of a purely resistive load on a lossless transmission line, then real-valued reflection coefficients are what you should expect, and you may already have a correct Smith chart.